# no desktop on a user when i log the user into the system

Tags: desktop-environments, user-management

On Ubuntu 18.04 after installing security controls, I am unable to log a new user in and have it generate a desktop the background displays. There is no taskbar or icons.  To create the user, I run [useradd -m {user name}](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/useradd.8.html).

This creates the user and its home directories, but once I log them in, they have no desktop. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `useradd` utility on most Linux systems does not assign a password for the created user. Without a password on the user, the user will be unable to login / have access to most of the functionality of the desktop.

To set a password for the user, you use the following command:

```
passwd <username>
```

Make sure to replace `<username>` with your actual username (without the angle brackets). After running this, you'll be prompted to enter a new password for the user. After setting a password for the user, you should be able to login as normal.

On the other hand, Ubuntu (like all Debian-based distros) comes with the `adduser` utility which is a user-friendly frontend to `useradd`. Simply running the following command is all you need:

```
adduser
```

You will be shown a series of prompts, which allow you to specify the settings for the new user (username, full name, etc.), and is preferred over `useradd` in modern Ubuntu versions, and unlike `useradd`, you don't have to manually set a password after; part of the setup will prompt you to set the password.